# Fill ROM with jump instructions

Tags: arm, assembly, cortex-m, linker

As I have heard it is a common practice to fill the unused flash memory of a microcontroller with an jump instruction to the reset function. This aids in resetting the MCU in case of the PC is corrupt, faster than the expiration of the watchdog timer.

I am currently interested in ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers. Which is the instruction I need? How to convert it to hex to place it in the linker script, how can I define the jump address I want?

What are the modifications needed in the linker script?

Comment: What tool chain are you using? A lot of times it's done by default.

Comment: I am using GCC. The point is however to learn how to do it, not depend on something doing it automatically.

Comment: You're making the assumption it's done the same in every tool chain and that is grossly incorrect. The only way to find this information is to read the appropriate documentation. Regardless, GCC doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Apart from what the toolchain does, the question is mostly about what should I feed on the FILL instruction in the linker script, which is ARM Cortex-M specific.

Answer (score 1):

Jump instructions are PC-relative on Cortex M and would need 32 bits unless your flash is really tiny.

A better idea would be the "permanently UNDEFINED" [instruction code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111140/410847) `0xDE00` or `0xDEDE` - all 16-bit `0xDEXX` instructions would trigger the UsageFault handler function. See [Output Section Fill](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Fill.html) in the LD manual.

Personally I would not bother:

- Without the Thumb-Bit all *even* addresses automatically trigger a fault while being loaded into the PC
- A *large* part of the 32 bit address space is *not* covered by the flash memory
- The PC should not be "randomly" modified unless we're talking about SEU in a highly radioactive environment

Comment: SEUs can be found even at ground level; Boeing did some research into random bit flipping in servers in Denver. See Xilinx UG116 for *sea level* SEU rates. SEUs happen regularly at altitude (it is atmospheric pressure dependent) and is something I need to evaluate on most of my designs (avionics).

Comment: That the PC _should_ not be randomly modified does not matter. This type of protection is to catch obscure errors in the code logic, bugs in the compiler or even in the chip logic itself (there will always be erratas..). It also helps during development.

Answer (score 1):

On a Cortex, jumping to address 0 is *NOT* equivalent to resetting the chip. The lower addresses contain the reset vectors, and the first two addresses specifically contain the initial PC and SP values. Not instructions, values. So you can't jump to 0 and expect something meaningfull to happen.

Note that even on a chip that does starts executing from an *instruction* at address 0, jumping to 0 would not reset all kinds of CPU and peripheral state, it is still not equivalent to a reset.

Comment: Never mentioned jumping to address 0. I want to jump to the address the reset function lies (e.g. NVIC_SystemReset()).

Comment: That would work if that function exist, except that your SP would not be initialized (and as I mention, neither would the other hardware revert to the post-reset state).